# How do I remove a corrupt AVD showing up in Windows 10?

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, avd-manager

I have a corrupt AVD showing up when I list AVDs. It doesn't show anywhere in Android Studio itself. How do I remove this? Uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio didn't help.

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk>emulator\emulator.exe -list-avds
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.18.db, detection is enabled for process: 18876
Medium_Phone_API_33
```

Comment: All AVD files are usually saved in `%USERPROFILE%\.android\avd`

Comment: Nothing there. I just realized that the problem is in emulator.exe than avds themselves because it shows the error regardless of -list-avds flag